# XCode 7.1.1 update, missing otool and git

Tags: terminal, xcode

I recently installed Xcode 7.1.1
After installation there seems to be problem with it.

`git` is missing

> Kaunteys-MacBook-Pro:~ Kaunteya$ git 2015-11-26 13:44:03.369
>   xcodebuild[2118:134190] ### Failed to load Addressbook class
>   CNContactNameFormatter sh: line 1:  2120 Segmentation fault: 11 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk
>   macosx -find git 2> /dev/null git: error: unable to find utility
>   "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

when i tried `brew install git`

> Kaunteys-MacBook-Pro:~ Kaunteya$ brew install git Warning: You are
>   using OS X 10.11. We do not provide support for this pre-release
>   version. You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
>   2015-11-26 13:45:16.185 xcodebuild[2144:137218] ### Failed to load
>   Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter sh: line 1:  2146
>   Segmentation fault: 11 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk
>   macosx -find otool 2> /dev/null otool: error: unable to find utility
>   "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH Error: Failure while
>   executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool

I also tried on other login on same Mac, but every thing is working fine there

Comment: you can reinstall xcode command line :https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?=command%20line%20tools

Comment: Ok. I will try that, But what about      Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter

Comment: @Kaunteya - did you ever work out the issue with regards to "Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter" ?

Comment: @arcseldon: I ended creating new user account.